# Dialog shows alpha Characters?

Tags: android, customdialog

Am using Custom Dialog  to shows the list of number based on user input,in Edittext box. I added Textwatcher everything is wrking fine until user try to give input more fast its showing one more Dialog with Black stripes with some alpha characters How to rectify this one?

My Screenshot is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cekZ.png)

[Custom Dialog code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634920/settext-to-edittextbox-from-dialog-content/10635027#10635027)

this is my code which am using in textwatcher

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String str = s.toString();
        str_length = str.length();
        Log.v("length_before", "" + count + "" + str_length);
        if (str_length == count + 1) {
            return;
        }
        if (str_length >= 3) {
            return;

        }

        if (str_length > count) {
            count = str.length();
            AmountDialog.amount_dialog(TicketIssueActivity.this, str,
                    amount);

        } else if (str_length < count) {
            count = str_length - 1;
            Log.v("length slese", "" + count + "" + str_length);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is number in amount field. you can set:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

in the EditText field of your layout xml file.

That's all I got from the question. Please post more details or code if this doesn't solve the  problem.

Comment: i used that one also but its not solved and i tried with input filters its also not wrking